# Calling a method instead of activity in onActivityResult

Tags: android

I am trying to implement `Places.autocomplete` using [this developer's guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#option_2_use_an_intent_to_launch_the_autocomplete_activity) and help here.
It is working fine, but, as normal, it is recalling the MainActivity. Hence, it is returning `lastknowonlocation` already in the `MainActivity`. I agree, this is a bad design, but an artifact of my zero experience with java.

Now, my question is, is it possible to call a method instead of `onActivityResult`, i.e. `setupViewPager`?

```
 public void onSearchCalled() {
    // Set the fields to specify which types of place data to return.
    List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.LAT_LNG);
    // Start the autocomplete intent.
    Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
        AutocompleteActivityMode.OVERLAY, fields) //no .setCountry...Search whole world
        .build(this);
    startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
  }
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
//        Log.i("LocationSearch", "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId() + ", " + place.getAddress());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ID: " + place.getId() + "address:" + place.getAddress() + "Name:" + place.getName() + " latlong: " + place.getLatLng(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//        String address = place.getAddress();
        if (place.getLatLng() !=null) {
          Lat = place.getLatLng().latitude;
          Long = place.getLatLng().longitude;
//          setupViewPager();
        } else {
          Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.location_not_found), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
      } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
        // TODO: Handle the error.
        Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: " + status.getStatusMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//        Log.i("LocationSearch", status.getStatusMessage());
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, `onActivityResult()` in itself is pointless without `startActivityForResult()`. Now, since autocomplete is handled in another activity (hence the `startActivityForResult()`), you're required to have `onActivityResult()` in order to read the result of said activity (in this case, the autocomplete value).

I don't judge, however please [understand the basic](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) first.